# How to remove trailing zeros in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a node element as 1.0123000. I am using an XSLT for transformation. I need the output as 1.0123. Any one have any idea how to do it in 1.0 version of XSLT?

Thanks in advance,
jo

Answer (score 9):

This is easier than you think! Just use `number()` and it will return the string `1.0123000` as a number `1.0123` in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number('1.0123000')"/>
```

will return

```
1.0123
```

The function `number()` can be found in the [XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions).